# Apache symlink to a folder outside of web root

Tags: apache, .htaccess, symlink

Here is the folder layout.

`/outside` is not normally accessible anywhere on example.com

`/public_html` is the folder for `http://example.com`

How can I use Apache's htaccess to make the url `http://example.com/outside/` to show content from the folder `/outside`?

Thanks!

Comment: Does it have to be done in .htaccess or are other solutions acceptable?

Comment: I am on shared hosting. It only allows the editing of .htaccess. I may consider switching to a VPS/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I use Apache's htaccess to make the url http://example.com/outside/ to show content from the folder /outside?

You can't. As far as I have [found out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218086/403-forbidden-on-symlink-in-web-root), Apache prevents directives in `.htaccess` files linking to locations outside the current web root.

You would have to do this in the central configuration:

```
Alias /outside /path/to/your/outside
```

You *may* be luckier with a symlink if you can turn `FollowSymLinks` on.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it but I just got a 500. And yes, im on shared hosting like you did in your question 2 yeas ago. Did you ever figure it out on shared hosting?

Maybe i'll switch to a vps.

Comment: @joshli if a symlink returns a 500, it won't work... You'd have to ask your hosting provider to do this for you. A VPS would be a solution to make it work - *if* it's worth switching to one for this

Comment: Ok. Thanks. So if I were to implement this on a VPS, do I just put the alias inside the httpd.conf file?