# How to allow Apache to serve files outside of the document root folder?

Tags: apache, ubuntu

everybody. TIA for your help.

All of my projects are located in /var/www/html and my apache.conf points to it with the following directive:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

By mistake I created another project in ~/Development/My_Project.
And I tried to get apache to serve the files using the following directive (right after the one above):

```
<Directory /Development/My_Project/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

But it does not work. I get:
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.

I appreciate any help.
Thanks

Comment: Since you enabled FollowSymLinks you could just create a symbolic link in your webroot with "ln -s [TARGET] [NAME]". In your case something like "ln -s ~/Development/My_Project My_Project" and now you should be able to access "http ://localhost/My_Project".

Comment: if your DocumentRoot is `/var/www/html` you should grant permissions to that folder, not the one above, still works, but unnecessary ;) `<Directory /var/www/html>`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apache symlink to a folder outside of web root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9325467/apache-symlink-to-a-folder-outside-of-web-root)