# Howto use path/directory outside the domain root via symlink without access to domain config?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, symlink

I am working an a shared hosting plattform which does not allow to edit or access the Apache config file.

The goal is to access the same files from two different domains which point to different domain roots:

```
test.example.com     --->   /test_root/web
public.example.com   --->   /public_root/web
```

Now I would like to access **the same** files using `test.example.com/some/files/...` and `public.example.com/some/files/...`

Of course I could simply copy the files to `/test_root/web/some/files/...` and to `/public_root/web/some/files/...` but this obviously just an example. In reality the files are a helpdesk system which should be integreated both into the test- and public-site. Copying the files would include maintaining two different systems, etc.

The goal is, to place the the files somewhere outside the two domain roots and make them available from both domains:

```
/test_root/web/some/files     --->   /path/to/some/files
/public_root/web/some/files   --->   /path/to/some/files
```

I created symlink to achive this (`ln -s ...`) but this does not work out. When I access on of the domains (e.g. test.example.com/some/files) I only get a blank page without any information what whent wrong.

I assume that the Apache is not configured to follow the symlinks. Without access to the Apache config I can neither check nor fix it.

Adding Symlinks to `.../web/.htacess` does not make any difference:

```
// test_root/web/.htaccess
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

**So the question is:** How can I make files outside the domain root available within a domain? Is this even possible? Is this possible using symlinks?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apache symlink to a folder outside of web root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9325467/apache-symlink-to-a-folder-outside-of-web-root)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in you `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} test.example.com/path/to/files [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://public.example.com/path/to/files [R=301,NC]
```

Test out this code. `/path/to/files` must be under `/public_root/web/`. 
Something like `/public_root/web/path/to/files/`

Comment: While this would work (redirect page A to page B), it is not a solution to the actual question, is it? The goal is not to redirect on page to the other but o serve the **exact same files** using different domains with different root dirs.

Comment: "The goal is to access the same files from two different domains which point to different domain roots" this is so far the only solution that came to my mind. Since you are using the exact same files on test.example.com and public.example.com @AndreiHerford

Comment: Since your subdomains are not pointing to the same webroot and you don't have access to apache config files to modify your document root path this might be the only solution that will work.

Comment: if you want to keep the same link you can try to edit `[R=301,NC]` with `[R=301,NC,P]`